# SUSE - Install PHP APC

Tags: php, sles11

I am using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11, I followed [a guide](http://heine.familiedeelstra.com/apc-on-suse)  to install APC, but I can't do the command of `phpize`, can someone tell me how to use this command?

Comment: Can you paste the error message you got?

Answer (score 1):

you need to install `php5-devel`